# angular fire valuechanges infinite loop

Tags: angular, firebase

Here is my requirement. Let’s say I have 3 check boxes bound to reactive form model .I create a form array using a model like

```
[{task:'abc', assigned:'true'},{task:'xyz',assigned:'false'},{task:'aaa',assigned:'true'}
```

My html form will show 3 check boxes
I want to integrate this with firestone
Question1: what will be best data model design? I am thinking to create an array type on the firestore document.
Question2.I am trying to use lesson on ‘advanced reactive form’ https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/auto-save-reactive-forms-with-firestore/ where the directive auto saves the reactive form data to firebase.
But I am going into infinite loop
As soon as User checks a checkbox data is saved to firestone but then .valueChanges() is getting fired that updates the form and again that triggers saving to firestore..
if I use take(1) infinite loop problem is solved but if multiple users are accessing the web app they will not get real time data. They will get latest data only when they refresh the page. That defeats the whole purpose of firestore.
How can I solve the infinite loop problem and still get real time data?